# This method must return a result of type byte[ ]

Tags: java, arrays, neo4j, byte

I am having this code in order to create a simple user-defined function for Neo4j.

```
public class Join {
    @UserFunction
    @Description("example.DES ,, Decryption of any input values.")
    public byte[] DES( @Name("set1") List<String> strings1) {

        for (int i = 0; i < strings1.size(); i++) {
            String dot;
            dot = strings1.get(i);
            try {
                KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
                SecretKey key = kg.generateKey();

                SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getEncoded(), "DES");

                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);

                byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(dot.getBytes());

                return cipherText;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But at : public byte[] DES(

I got this error:

This method must return a result of type byte[ ], so any suggestion please.

Comment: Where do you get this error?

Comment: What does it return if an exception occurs?

Comment: at :  public byte[] DES(

Comment: One potential solution: Get rid of the try catch and instead declare your method to throw the most specific exceptions that need to be thrown.

Comment: Side note: what happens to the rest of the strings in the list after the first of them is encrypted successfully?

Comment: And it's funny to have a `return` inside a `for loop` ...

Comment: @logisima, but it is not funny for some one who is beginner in java

Comment: I formatted your code but in the future please use editor which can format code for you (thanks to proper indentation problems can be seen easier). Anyway as @HovercraftFullOfEels tried to imply in his first comment your code doesn't handle scenario where exception will be thrown before `return` statement (you have only one). Also logisima has good point about placing return in loop since in your scenario it may defeat its purpose because `return` will move control-flow out of your method which also means out of your loop.

Comment: sara: I think that @logisima meant "funny" to mean unusual or unexpected. It really is code that doesn't make sense, and their suggestion should be taken as a suggestion for you to re-think your algorithm so that it makes more logical sense.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  Thank you very much,, I really appreciate all your answer, just as I am so beginner at Java I am trying to solve this problem